# use jsonreader.setlenient(true) to accept malformed json at line 1 column 1 path $

Tags: php, mysql, android, json, retrofit

Tengo el siguiente error en mi proyecto y no se a que se debe me podrian apoyar

No encuentro la verdad donde este el error esto es lo que me muestra el logcat cada que ejecuto la app e intento cargar las imagenes al server y base de datos. Le cambie la direccion IP incluso quite el `true` de mi archivo PHP en la linea `$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), true);`.

De igual manera en las dependencias tengo segun android la mas reciente no se si tenga alguna desactualizada y sea por eso

```
dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'

    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.9.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-scalars:2.9.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'

    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.7.2'

}
```

Error

`Use JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at line 1 column 1 path $`

`Codigo`

MultiUpload.java

```
public class MultiUpload extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button btnAdd, btnSubmit;
    private ListView imageList;
    private List<Uri> images = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_multi_upload);

        btnAdd = findViewById(R.id.btn_add);
        btnSubmit = findViewById(R.id.btn_upload);
        imageList = findViewById(R.id.image_list);

        btnAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent gallery = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                gallery.setType("image/*"); //allow any image file type.
                gallery.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
                startActivityForResult(gallery, 1);
            }
        });

        btnSubmit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                uploadToServer();
            }
        });

    }


    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if(resultCode !=RESULT_CANCELED){

            switch (requestCode){
                case 1:
                    if(resultCode == RESULT_OK && data !=null){

                        int count = data.getClipData().getItemCount();
                        for(int i=0; i<count; i++){
                            Uri image = data.getClipData().getItemAt(i).getUri();
                            String imagePath = FileUtils.getPath(MultiUpload.this,image);
                            images.add(Uri.parse(imagePath));
                        }

                        ImageListAdapter adapter = new ImageListAdapter(MultiUpload.this,images);
                        imageList.setAdapter(adapter);
                    }
            }

        }
    }

    //method to call api to upload files to server
    public void uploadToServer(){

       List<MultipartBody.Part> list = new ArrayList<>();
       for(Uri uri: images){
           list.add(prepairFiles("file[]", uri));
       }

        HttpService service = RetrofitBuilder.getClient().create(HttpService.class);
        Call<FileModel> call = service.callMultipleUploadApi(list);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<FileModel>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<FileModel> call, Response<FileModel> response) {
                FileModel model = response.body();
                Toast.makeText(MultiUpload.this, model.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<FileModel> call, Throwable t) {
                Toast.makeText(MultiUpload.this, t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

    }

    @NonNull
    private MultipartBody.Part prepairFiles(String partName, Uri fileUri){
        File file = new File( fileUri.getPath());
        RequestBody requestBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/*"), file);

        return  MultipartBody.Part.createFormData(partName, file.getName(), requestBody);
    }
}
```

RetrofitBuilder

```
public class RetrofitBuilder {

    private static Retrofit retrofit = null;

    public static Retrofit getClient(){

        final OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .readTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .connectTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .build();
        if(retrofit ==null){
            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl("http://172.30.99.135/")
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .client(okHttpClient)
                    .build();
        }
        return  retrofit;
    }
}
```

HttpService.java

```
public interface HttpService {

    @Multipart
    @POST("TestRampas/UploadApi/RestApi/upload_api.php")
    Call<FileModel> callUploadApi(@Part MultipartBody.Part image);

    @Multipart
    @POST("TestRampas/UploadApi/RestApi/multi_upload.php")
    Call<FileModel> callMultipleUploadApi(@Part List<MultipartBody.Part> image);
}
```

FileModel.java

```
public class FileModel {
    public String message;
    public Boolean status;

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public Boolean getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(Boolean status) {
        this.status = status;
    }
}
```

multi_upload.php

```
<?php

//adding headers for rest api
header("Content-Type: application/json");
header("Acess-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Acess-Control-Allow-Methods: POST"); // here is define the request method

include 'dbconfig.php'; // include database connection file

$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), true); // collect input parameters and convert into readable format

// getting the number of total number of files 
$countfiles = count($_FILES['file']['name']);
$file = $_FILES['file']['name'][0]; // getting first file

if(empty($file))
{
    // if file is empty show error
    $errorMSG = json_encode(array("message" => "please select image", "status" => false));  
    echo $errorMSG;
}
else
{

$upload_path = 'upload/'; // declare file upload path
$valid_extensions = array('jpeg', 'jpg', 'png', 'gif'); // valid image extensions - file extensions

// Looping all files 
for($i=0;$i<$countfiles;$i++){
    $fileName = $_FILES['file']['name'][$i];
    $tempPath = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'][$i];
    $fileSize  =  $_FILES['file']['size'][$i];

    $fileExt = strtolower(pathinfo($fileName,PATHINFO_EXTENSION)); // get image extension

    // check if the files are contain the vALID  extensions
    if(in_array($fileExt, $valid_extensions))
    {               
        //check file not exist our upload folder path
        if(!file_exists($upload_path . $fileName))
        {
            // check file size '5MB' - 5MegaByte is allowed
            if($fileSize < 5000000){

                //built-in method to move file to directory
                move_uploaded_file($tempPath, $upload_path . $fileName); // move file from system temporary path to our upload folder path 
                
                //insert into database table
                $query =  mysqli_query($conn,'INSERT into tbl_image (name) VALUES("'.$fileName.'")');
                
            }
            else{       
                $errorMSG = json_encode(array("message" => "Sorry, your file is too large, please upload 5 MB size", "status" => false));   
                echo $errorMSG;
            }
        }
        else
        {       
            $errorMSG = json_encode(array("message" => "Sorry, file already exists check upload folder", "status" => false));   
            echo $errorMSG;
        }
    }
    else
    {       
        $errorMSG = json_encode(array("message" => "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed", "status" => false));   
        echo $errorMSG;     
    }
   
   }
}

//if no error message show response
if(!isset($errorMSG))
{   
    echo json_encode(array("message" => "Image Uploaded Successfully", "status" => true));  
}

?>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: El mensaje de error es claro: estás recibiendo un JSON mal formado. En `multi_upload.php` hay partes no cubiertas, puede que el código pase por ahí, o puede que alguno de los archivos que incluyes esté emitiendo alguna salida por pantalla que está rompiendo el JSON. Haz debug de la respuesta en `RetrofitBuilder` y podrás ver lo que está respondiendo el servidor exactamente.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvi el error de la siguiente manera en mi clase `RetrofitBuilder`

Agregue la variable `gson` y quedo de la siguiente manera

```
public class RetrofitBuilder {

    private static Retrofit retrofit = null;

    public static Retrofit getClient(){

        final OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .readTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .connectTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .build();
        if(retrofit ==null){

            Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                    .setLenient()
                    .create();

            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl("http://192.168.100.71/")
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                    .client(okHttpClient)
                    .build();
        }
        return  retrofit;
    }
}
```

El inconveniente ahora es que me muestra el siguiente error

`java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $`

Investigue y he encontrado que debo formatear el codigo pero sinceramente no se como. Me podrian ayudar

Comment: Ya lo solucione el nombre de mi base de datos en el php no coincidia con el que tenia creado en xampp .